# How to add DOM object on canvas

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, html5-canvas

The thing is about a markup tool on canvas.

First, I could draw arrow, line or rectangle on canvas.
Then, I could select the things I drew on canvas. For example. if I click the arrow, it will show a dotted square around it to show that I have selected it.

At first, I thought I could put a div element around the arrow and hidden it. Then if I click the div element and show this element just look like I selected the arrow.

But I find out that I could not put other DOM element on canvas.

So there is anyone know how to do it?
Or anyone know some other ways to implement it?
It could be perform with js libraries. I tried some existing framework but didn't get a clue.

Comment: `you can use some javascript library.` it is the end of you homework?

Comment: No, it's not my homework.

Comment: Then write like: `It could be perform with js libraries`. This question shows, that you didn't search and did enough to understand a problem, you just want to someone solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about starting with something like this :
http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes

You also can take a look at existing frameworks like [kineticJs](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/)

Comment: Have you ever used an existing javascript frameworks named closure or Mochikit???(P.S I have read the page and it likes an idea I first come up but later I thought it could be too complicate. But now it seems the only solution. )

Comment: I never used those, but the purpose of a framework is that it makes it easy for developers by providing a nice and easy APIs and functions.